# Turn off Outlook new email notifications for specific duration

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way with VBA in Outlook 2013 to turn off new email notifications for a specified duration of time? I work a lot out of email, and am currently attempting to use the Pomodoro technique for maintaining focus. To stop myself from switching attention to newly arrived emails while doing a Pomodoro, I'd like to be able to turn notifications off for a period of 30 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried to increase send&receive timer?

Answer (score 0):

The UI notification options for newly delivered emails can be changed by setting a registry key, but the changes won't take effect until Outlook is restarted.  Otherwise there is no option in the Outlook Object Model to reliably turn off receiving for all accounts as disabling send/receive will not affect Exchange or Office 365 accounts.  Your best option is to automate clicking the Work Offline ribbon button on the Send/Receive tab.